# how to specify mvc3 action links with knockout templates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a knockout template (using koExternaltemplateEngine_all.js) in which I want an edit link that will direct to a controller/action. I quite like what knockout provides for me in terms of MVVM, but uncertain if I'm trying to mix apples and oranges by specifying an action link in a knockout view. I'd like to knock what is the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

```
<p>
  <b><span data-bind='text: Title'></span></b>
  <span data-bind='text: ArticleDate'></span>
</p>
<span data-bind='text: BodyText'></span>
```

Something like

```
<a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Details" .. ?
```

The Model

```
    public class SecureModel
    {
       public SecureModel()
       {

       }

       private List<Article> _articles;

       public List<Article> Announcements
       {
          get
          {
              return _articles;
          }
          set
          {
              _articles = value;
          }
       }
    }
```

View

```
    @model UI.Models.SecureModel
    @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Announcements";
    }
    var viewModel = {

    isEditable: ko.observable(false),
    articles: ko.mapping.fromJS([]),
    loadInitialData: function () {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData, dataMappingOptions, viewModel.articles);
    },
    loadUpdatedData: function () {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(serverData, dataMappingOptions, viewModel.articles);
    }
};
```

Comment: I answered but now I'm wondering.... Did you just want to know if doing this was good practice OR did you want to know how to do it?

Comment: Hi @klabranche thanks for the reply. I think you have the right idea, I'm currently receiving a knockout error : unable to parse bindings..unterminated string constant when I try that line of code ( setting ArticleModelKeyFieldName as Id ) currently, but I'll try to make it run and report back. Definitely interested to know opinions if this is even a good idea, to me the knockout/external templates with model binding seems to break the normal paradigm of binding a razor view to a server side model?

Comment: Using a server side model with KO is normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading your code right then you have already scoped to the `Article` since your first KO data-bind samples show Title, ArticleDate, etc....  It's a little hard to tell since you don't show what `Article` has for properties...

If this is the case you should be able to do something like this:

```
<a data-bind="attr: { 'href': '@Url.Action("Details", "ControllerName", new {actionParameterName=ArticleModelKeyFieldName}">Details</a>
```

Where `actionParameterName` is the name of the parameter in your action and `ArticleModelKeyFieldName` is the key field on your Articles Model.

So if you had an action like:

```
public ActionResult Details(int articleId)
{
....
}
```

Then `actionParameterName` would be articleId.